# How to print strings from file with out using getline() function in C++

Tags: c++

I wanted to read huge input as a sting but it doesn't work on my linux box. When I tried to insert string ( huge) , it stopped me to add any character once I reached 2998 character.

```
std::string s;
std::cin.clear();
cout<< "Enter string"<<endl;;
getline(cin, s);
```

So I  decided to add the huge string  in a file and read from there. Now I have a  file which **contains only a single line** , how would I print the string (  getline() doesn't work because it can not read more than 2998 bytes in my linux system ).

For example I have following input ( part of a file),

```
cat\n\ndog\ts\n\n\nmarket\g\he\n
```

Output should be:

```
cat
dog\ts
market\g\he
```

Appreciate your help.

Comment: You could use `std::istream::get()` to read the string char by char.

Comment: You have drawn an incorrect conclusion -- it is not `std::getline()` with the limit, it is your terminal! That said, reading a massive string sounds like a design error. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Where is this 2998 bytes limitation coming from ? The next obvious solution is to read in chunks and do some minor processing before printing it out line by line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you do something similar to this with ifstream?

```
BUFFER_MAX = 3000; //Whatever you want to be
char[BUFFER_MAX] buffer;
std::cin.getline(buffer,BUFFER_MAX-1);
```

This is just from going off of this documentation: [`std::istream::getline()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline).